# How to exclude a category from Jekyll blog index?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a category called "tachartasan" which I have excluded from my index page however the posts in this category are still being counted in the pagination which is currently set to 10 posts per page.

7 of my most recent posts have been in the tachartasan category and it has resulted in my [front page](https://macmhicheil.github.io/GeidhUK/) showing only 3 posts total.

```
    <div class="container">
        {% for post in paginator.posts %}
        {% unless post.categories contains 'tachartasan' %}
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}"><img src="{{ post.image }}" class="index-image"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <h5 class="post-title"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
              {% if post.author %}
              <p class="text-muted">{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }} le <a href="{{ post.author_url }}">{{ post.author }}</a></p>
              {% else %}
              <p class="text-muted">{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }} le <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/mu-dheidhinn/">Crìstean MacMhìcheil</a></p>
              {% endif %}
              {{ post.excerpt }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
        {% endunless %}
        {% endfor %}

        <!-- Pagination -->
        <nav>
          <ul class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-lg">
            {% if paginator.next_page %}
              <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/duilleag-{{paginator.next_page}}">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% else %}
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}

            <li class="page-item disabled">
              <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
                Duilleag {{ paginator.page }} / {{ paginator.total_pages }}
              </a>
            </li>

            {% if paginator.previous_page %}
              {% if paginator.page == 2 %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              {% else %}
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/duilleag-{{paginator.previous_page}}">
                    <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                  </a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% else %}
              <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
              </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

I don't want the hidden "tachartasan" posts to be counted as part of the 10 posts per page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line to the front matter of my excluded posts solved it. They are hidden on the index page and no longer counted against the pagination limit and are still visible on the specific category page.

```
hidden: true
```